# can i use PHP standard recomendation(PSR) in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can i use PSRs in wordpress vs the WordPress Coding Standards?

I am going to create a plugin but I want to use psrs and take advantage of all its features.

- psr4
- libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, and it is best to use it for plugin development.
But as you know it is not recommended by the wordpress community one reason is it can be problematic if other plugins or the theme share identical packages installed via `composer`

But to use `PSR4` or somthing similar just start your project with a `composer.json` and structure it with the correct file path for development for your plugin. Look at the example snippet below  declaring  `autoload` in `composer.json` followed by the `PSR` and the path

EXAMPLE: `composer.json`

```
    {
        "name": "author/myplugin",
        "type": "wordpress-plugin",
        "description": "Description",
        "require": {
           "php": ">=7.4"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "MYPLUGIN\\": "src/Includes/"
            }
        }
    }
```